# How to open a LaTeX file in Python that starts with a comment

Tags: python, latex

[image: Trying to open this file in python]

Code:

```
import os
import re
import time
import csv
from TexSoup import TexSoup


path = os.getcwd()
texFile = path + '\\Paper16.tex'
print(texFile)

soup = TexSoup(open(texFile, 'r'))
```

This returns no output when I try to `print(soup)` and I believe it is because the first line starts with %.

Comment: Perhaps you could share the *tex file, but not sure what you mean "does not return output". You have not printed anything except texFile, which is just the name of the file with the path. What will happen if you `print(soup)`?

Comment: Thanks for responding @msi_gerva. Sorry for not including that i did try to print(soup) but it returns nothing. Console is just blank.

Comment: I tried with random file, which starts with '%' and the TexSoup was able to parse it. Can you share your LaTex file?

Comment: Sure. I am trying to share LaTex file but it doesn't let me. Please help me on this.

Comment: @msi_gerva Please find the LaTex file : https://app.box.com/s/0rjt27qqxxi2imwy7dr8xmps3xa3202h

Answer (score 0):

I think this is some sort of bug of TexSoup.

Namely, if you remove the first line or comment out second line instead, the TexSoup is able to parse the file and `print(soup)` will give some output.

In addition, if you terminate the first line by adding braces:

```
%{\documentstyle[aps,epsf,rotate,epsfig,preprint]{revtex}}
```

the TexSoup is also able to parse the file.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. I noticed previously by manually removing the first line and print(soup) did work. I did not understand how to work on it without manual intervention.

Comment: I suggest contacting directly with TexSoup group. You should be able to do that at:https://github.com/alvinwan/TexSoup/issues